# How to find a list of sites that I've authenticated with using my Google OpenID?

Tags: openid, google-account

I use [Google's Profile](http://www.google.com/profiles) feature when logging into sites that support OpenID.

Is there a way for me to get a list of all the websites that I have logged into using my Google Profile as my OpenID.

Comment: See also: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5521/which-google-services-have-i-signed-up-for

Comment: Nowadays: [gmail - Google suite legacy migration](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/162448/google-suite-legacy-migration/162582#162582)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

While logged in, you can visit

https://www.google.com/accounts/IssuedAuthSubTokens

to see all of the websites that google has issued authentication tokens for.

Comment: I had accidentally accepted 'always remember' on localhost one time while debugging. Glad to know how to revoke it now.

Comment: Still working in 2014

Comment: Still works in 2022, however it redirects to  https://myaccount.google.com/permissions. So incase they ever disable the direct, that is the page to visit and be sure to scroll down the page to find the "Signing in with Google" items.

Answer (score 9):

Visit your Google Account Settings.

Under "Personal Settings" click "Change authorized websites."

This will list all websites that you have logged into via Google's OpenID service.

Comment: +1 this one actually got recorded 29 seconds before the accepted

Answer (score 0):

Go to: [myaccount.google.com/permissions](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions)

You can then view websites with account access, and also view websites that are only signed in with Google.