# Which Google services have I signed up for?

Tags: google-account

I have three Gmail accounts. All of them have been used to sign up for different Google services. Is there a page somewhere that tells me which services are associated with my accounts?

Comment: The account might also be associated with 3rd party sites via OpenID. See: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/978/how-to-find-a-list-of-sites-that-ive-authenticated-with-using-my-google-openid

Comment: Related and uptodate: [gmail - Google suite legacy migration](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/162448/google-suite-legacy-migration/162582#162582)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can check all the information Google has on you on the [Google Dashboard](https://www.google.com/dashboard/).

Comment: You can get to that page by going to: Google Account Settings > View data stored with this account

Answer (score 8):

View your [Account Settings](https://www.google.com/accounts/ManageAccount) and look at the My Products section.