# Google suite legacy migration

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business

My family is using the legacy free forever Google suite. Forever ends in June and we will become paying over 200€ per year. Microsoft 365 for family is much cheaper. The only blocker is Google account used everywhere - android, google analytics and many 3rd party websites where I have authorized over time.

My silly and naive question is, if my account will be preserved when the suite will be shut down. I just need an authorization like ordinary gmail users.

Comment: Lovely comment, **"Forever ends in June"**. I didn't remmember this selling point but now that you mention it, yeah, that was it, this thing was forever. I think the system was badly abused with folks selling legacy domains with terabytes of storage for thousand of dollars. Google should have put an end to that instead of killing their promise... Anyway, now it's a done deal, lets do what we gotta do. </endrant>

Answer (score 2):

There's something I'm not seeing on [@Rubén's linked support article](https://support.google.com/a/answer/100458?hl=en#zippy=%2Cwhat-data-is-included-in-my-export) that is "sites we used this account to sign up".

I found this couple of a decade old questions and answers:

- [Which Google services have I signed up for?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5521/which-google-services-have-i-signed-up-for)
- [How to find a list of sites that I've authenticated with using my Google OpenID?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/978/how-to-find-a-list-of-sites-that-ive-authenticated-with-using-my-google-openid)

The old links/interface/articles don't exist anymore. But looking for their equivalents today I found this:

1. Go to your security settings: https://myaccount.google.com/security
2. Look for this:
   [image: third-party apps with account access]
3. And this: [image: signing into other sites]

From the article [Manage third-party accounts you've linked with Google - Google Account Help](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/2541991?hl=en) we can find another link of interest:
https://myaccount.google.com/accountlinking. But there was nothing for me there...
<kbd>[image: linked accounts]</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

[G Suite legacy free edition](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2855120) says that the domains using it will be transitioned to Google Workspace and users could use it at no cost for few weeks.

As it doesn't mention a way to opt-out of this, IMHO it's fair to think that you will have to follow the instructions of [Export your organization's data](https://support.google.com/a/answer/100458?hl=en) to move part of your data out of G Suite / Google Workspace. Unfortunately there are some types of data that aren't supported by the export tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can export your domain data by following https://support.google.com/a/answer/100458?hl=en

Or https://www.cubebackup.com/docs/tutorials/migrate-from-gsuite-legacy-edition/

Google now offers a 50% discount for the upgrade.