# How to list the sites I've authenticated with using a Yahoo OpenId?

Tags: openid, yahoo

Along the same vein of [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/978/), is there any way to list the sites authorized with a particular Yahoo openId account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Log in to Yahoo
- In the top left next to your name click the down arrow
- Select `Account Info`
- Sign In again if required
- In the `Sign-In and Security` you can either select

  - `Manage/Create your OpenID`
  - `Manage Apps and Website Connections`