# How to view which sites I am signed in that use Google Course Builder

Tags: google-account

I recently registered to a site that uses Google Course Builder (more specifically [Data Mining with WEKA](https://weka.waikato.ac.nz/dataminingwithweka/preview)) using my Google Account, but I cannot find any section in my Google Account Settings that lists the permissions that I have granted to this site and what sites like this I have granted permission in the past.

I have searched in [this list](https://www.google.com/accounts/IssuedAuthSubTokens) as proposed by [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/980/108237) but the site was not listed there.

Any ideas on where it is and how to view this list of sites?

Comment: That would seem to be the right location. I, at least, can see other sites that I've used the Google OAuth to sign in with. (An alternative URL is https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer

You should ask for the name of the apps used on the related course to each course responsible.

## Partial explanation

Google Course Builder isn't a Web App. It's software and guidelines that could be used to create online courses which in turn could work as web apps. Each course could include one or several components that requires user authorization but the name of each component depend on each organization or even individuals behind each course / component.

## Registration permission request

The following screen shot is shown to me after I clicked on the Registration link on  [Data Mining with WEKA](https://weka.waikato.ac.nz/dataminingwithweka/preview)

[image: Application requesting permission]

## Quotes

---

From https://www.google.com/edu/openonline/course-builder/index.html

> Course Builder is an Open Source (Apache 2.0), online education
>   platform. Use it to create your online course whether it's for an
>   entire university offering, professional training, or a corporate
>   product.

From https://www.google.com/edu/openonline/course-builder/docs/1.10/create-a-course/add-content/google-drive.html

> #### OAuth consent screen details
>
> When your site requires access to private data (such as a file on
>   Google Drive), the owner of the account will be asked to consent to
>   the access. To prepare the consent screen to ask for access, you must
>   provide a product name and an email address.
>
> 1. Click the OAuth consent screen tab.
> 2. Fill out the fields:
>
>    - For Email address, select one of the valid addresses.
>    - For Product name show to users, enter the name of your course or site.
>    - Considering ignoring the other fields, which are optional.
> 3. Click Save.

Comment: If course builder is not a Web App (and thus the WEKA online course website) and during the registration process I was not presented with a screen that asks my permission to allow the particular website to have access to some aspects of my account (like Google Drive), then the only shared information is just my email address ? Shouldn't this however be somehow visible. I mean the websites that I have logged in using Google Sign In?

Comment: The comment has two questions. 1. Yes. 2. I don't think so, as passing the email address is a one time only event.